# Set vagrant VM's proxy for Chef

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I've set up a very basic infrastructure that contains a workstation, an opscode hosted chef server and a vagrant VM node.

On my workstation I used the command `vagrant up`. This downloaded the vagrant VM to set up a node. However the vagrant VM node is not able to connect to the Internet. How to I change the VM's proxy settings?

Comment: Try vagrant-proxyconf plugin to set up proxies for package managers and shells.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [vagrant-proxyconf](http://tmatilai.github.io/vagrant-proxyconf/) plugin:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
```

Then configure it for all VMs using `$HOME/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile`. For example something like:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.proxy.http     = "http://192.168.0.2:3128/"
  config.proxy.https    = "http://192.168.0.2:3128/"

  # exclude your internal networks, including the Vagrant ones
  config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1,192.168.33.*,.example.com"
end
```